# How to guarantee xTimerChangePeriod within ms resolution?

Tags: timer, arm, freertos

I've been using xTimerChangePeriod to perform LED animation on an ARM Cortex-M3 (running freeRTOS). I have no access to PWM so that's why I'm doing it with the timer task.

The animation is essentially a timer callback that sets LED intensity at various interval. Between each callback, I use xTimerChangePeriod to change the delay to give the LEDs a fading in and out effect.
However, I noticed that while often when specifying delays at 32ms the timer will happily give me a delay only +/-10ms off, sometimes it will get a hiccup a delay for ~375ms (I used the millisecond counter to measure this).

Maybe timer task is being blocked somewhere by other higher task? Is there a way I can guarantee the timer delay to not be blocked for that long?

Answer (score 0):

What's the scheduler frequency? Is it 1kHz? You can make the timer daemon task's priority highest in the system, so this way it will never be preempted by anything else.

`#define configTIMER_TASK_PRIORITY      (configMAX_PRIORITIES - 1)`

It's also possible, that you do something "wrong" (like blocking operations) within other timer handler function...

Comment: I have the timer task on highest priority. It's possible that I might have blocking operations within other timer handler, I'll have to do a run through to investigate further.